# How do I separate words in a given text in R?

Tags: r, text-mining

For example I have a text file with content as follows:

```
I wantto separate those wordswhich arejoined.
```

How do I separate the words in this text so that I get this as output.

```
I want to separate those words which are joined.
```

Basically, something which can detect meaningless words from the text and make them meaningful.

For example, the code should detect that "wantto" does not make any sense and after processing it, it should be able to return "want to" as output.

It may return some other meaningful combination of words but that is fine.

Comment: Do you have a dictionary available? E.g. from a spell checker?

Comment: I did not. But now I have downloaded aspell and english dictionary which aspell provides after looking at the answer by gagolews!

Comment: That trick **NEVER** works.   "bookkeeper" ?   Is there a word inside "cl*ass*ic"?  Or the internet-famous location in North Lincolnshire, England:  Scunthorpe?

Comment: You could try a greedy algorithm: from left to right accumulate characters until you match a word in the dictionary. Treat that as a "candidate split", then repeat for the rest of the word. If you're left with a non-word, your algorithm needs to backtrack.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Or the themepark in North Yorkshire, Lightwater Valley

Comment: Send the string to an R script (in RStudio) and then spell check the script.

Comment: [This R-Bloggers link](http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-spell-checker-in-r/) may be useful.  It brings up a new question for me...is it possible to spell-check an R script from the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am attaching a **quick and dirty code** that should help you to correct atleast two word spelling errors without using the aspell. The dictionary I used is the big.txt from Peter Norvig's site which should be enough for common words. You can use the `correctSentence` function to see the results

```
## big.txt Taken for Peter Norvig's basic spell checker data file
words <- scan("http://norvig.com/big.txt", what = character())

split_matches <-function(word) {
num_char <- nchar(word)
return_str <- character()
start_pos <- 0
end_pos <- num_char
for(i in 1:num_char)
{
    str <- substr(word,1,num_char-i+1)
    if(str %in% words)
    {
      return_str <- str
      start_pos <- nchar(return_str)
      break
    }

 }
 return_str <- c(return_str,substr(word,start_pos+1,end_pos))
 return_str

}

correctSentence <- function(sentence) {
  list_of_words <- strsplit(sentence," ")
  list_of_words  <- list_of_words[[1]]
  num_words <- length(list_of_words)

  output_str <- character()
  for(i in 1:num_words){
  word <- list_of_words[i]
  if(word %in% words) {
      paste(output_str,word,sep=" ")
      output_str <- c(output_str,word)
  }
  else {
     output_str <- c(output_str,split_matches(word))
  }

}
  output_str <-paste(output_str,collapse=" ")
  output_str
}
# test this with your sentence
correctSentence("I wantto separate those wordswhich arejoined")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have aspell (see `?aspell` installed), this may give you a hint:

```
> writeLines("I wantto separate those wordswhich arejoined.", "/tmp/test.txt")
> sp <- aspell('/tmp/test.txt')
> sp
arejoined
  /tmp/test.txt:1:36

wantto
  /tmp/test.txt:1:3

wordswhich
  /tmp/test.txt:1:25
> sp[[5]]
[[1]]
 [1] "want to" "want-to" "want"    "wanton"  "Watt"    "watt"    "wand"    "went"    "wont"    "whatnot" "wants"   "canto"  
[13] "panto"   "Wanda"   "waned"   "won't"   "want's"  "wanted"  "NATO"    "vanity"  "wander"  "winter"  "wart"    "natty"  
[25] "vaunt"   "wan"     "ant"     "walnut"  "wasn't"  "Witt"    "wait"    "wane"    "wino"   

[[2]]
 [1] "words which" "words-which" "wordsmith"   "Wordsworth"  "words"       "Woodstock"   "word's"      "woodsier"   
 [9] "Woods"       "wards"       "woods"       "ward's"      "woad's"      "wood's"      "wort's"     

[[3]]
[1] "are joined" "are-joined" "rejoined"   "adjoined"   "enjoined"   "rejoinder"  "regained"
```

Anyway, such a task will always be dictionary-based.